# i can't found '_weakref.py',where is '_weakref.py'

Tags: python

```
from _weakref import (
     getweakrefcount,
     getweakrefs,
     ref,
     proxy,
     CallableProxyType,
     ProxyType,
     ReferenceType)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Python-coded module, it's a C-coded Python-extension module.

You can read the extension module's C source code [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/_weakref.c?revision=59564&view=markup).

Comment: hi,alex
i see the doc
but i can't find the "proxy" fucntion
how can i get the mean of 'proxy'.

Comment: Lines 60 to 76 (at the URL I gave) define and document the `proxy` function.  Ctrl-F or Apple-F on your browser opened at the URL I already gave, searching for proxy, reveals that in about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

`_weakref` is a C module that comes with Python. Having said that, you should never import a module starting with an underscore directly; import the Python module and let it deal with the C module as needed, in this case `weakref`.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but you say that "you should never import a module starting with an underscore" however, that module is being imported from other python modules... so, they were developed by python developers.. for example, this module is being called from _weakrefset.py and from weakref.py (notice that it is no underscore here)

Comment: @jstuardo: By "you" I mean J. Random Programmer. Obviously if you've written it yourself and are writing the associated public modules then you would know when and where to properly import it.